# I couldn't trigger sound alert after user's action on Flutter (based on Kotlin error after AudioPlayers package added)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on a Flutter project for an Android application.
I need to give sound alerts when the user's action is completed success or wrong.

I've tried the AudioPlayers package but it didn't work.

> version: audioplayers: ^0.20.1

```
playMusic() async {
    await audioPlayer.play(url, isLocal: true);
  }
```

I even couldn't build the project after adding audioplayers.

[image]

Is there any other package for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I added to AudioPlayers package to pubseck.yaml It was giving Kotlin error.

First I change my Kotlin version to 1.5.10 from 1.30.50 in 'android/build.gradle'.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
```

And then the app started to give multidex errors.

I changed the configuration of 'android/app/build.gradle' like below

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    }       

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.allstore_mobile"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

After the above changes, the AudioPlayers package started to work.

```
final AudioCache _audioCache = AudioCache(
    prefix: 'assets/sounds/',
    fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP),
  );

_audioCache.play('success.mp3');
```